# ggplot2: how to manually adjust scale_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made 2 bubble plots called beta and km. I would like to compare the plots side-by-side but the scale_area seem to be different which makes it difficult to visually compare 2 plots based on the size of the bubbles.

If you notice the legends on the plots below, the scales are different.  I think it is because highest BiasAM value on the betaGSD5 dataset ~ 64 and kmGSD5 data =100.

How can I manually change the scale_area such that the betaPlot scale match the kmPlot scale?

Also is it possible to manually set the legend breaks? Instead of being automatically generated, can specify I the legend however I want like this?
0-10,
10-30,
30-50,
50-70,
70-100,

> 100

betaGSD5 data: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63947093/betaGSD5.csv

kmGSD5 data: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63947093/kmGSD5.csv

Here is beta plot code

```
betaPlot <- ggplot(betaGSD5, aes(N,PctCens,size=BiasAM,label=NULL)) +
  geom_point(colour="red", shape=16) +scale_area(to=c(1,10)) +
  xlab("Sample size") + ylab("Percent censored") +
  xlim(0,100)+ ylim(0,100) +
  theme_bw()+
  opts(
 #legend.position='none',
  panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
  panel.background = theme_blank(),
  axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
  axis.title.x=theme_text(face='bold',vjust=0.2, size =12), #size=15 #hjust:move     horizonal, vjust-move verticall
  axis.title.y=theme_text(face='bold',angle=90, vjust=0.2,size =12))
print(betaPlot)
```

[image]

KM plot

```
kmPlot <- ggplot(kmGSD5, aes(N,PctCens,size=NewBiasAMpct,label=NULL)) +
    geom_point(colour="red", shape=16) +scale_area(to=c(1,10)) +
    xlab("Sample size") + ylab("Percent censored") +
    xlim(0,100)+ ylim(0,100) +
    theme_bw()+
    opts(
      #legend.position='none',
     panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
     panel.background = theme_blank(),
     axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
     axis.title.x=theme_text(face='bold',vjust=0.2, size =12), #size=15 #hjust:move       horizonal, vjust-move verticall
     axis.title.y=theme_text(face='bold',angle=90, vjust=0.2,size =12))

 print(kmPlot)
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `?scale_area` and `?continuous_scale`

Comment: @mnel: I did.  Not very helpful.

Comment: @Amateur, what was not helpful? What did you not understand?

Comment: I'm sorry.I meant I did not find ?scale_area instructions helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want them side-by-side then it's very easy. Just combine both dataset and use facet_wrap()

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = N, y = PctCens, size = BiasAM, label = NULL)) +
  geom_point(colour="red", shape = 16) + 
  scale_size_area(limits = c(1, 10), breaks = c(0, 10, 30, 50, 70, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Sample size", limits = c(0, 100)) + 
  scale_y_continuous("Percent censored", limits = c(0, 100)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Method) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = 'bold', vjust = 0.2, size = 12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = 'bold', angle = 90, vjust = 0.2, size = 12)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great, exactly what I needed. But I'm running into some issues with ggplot depreciation errors (legend breaks especially). Is there an updated version of this code for the new ggplot?